# Boot fails after reinstall GRUB

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2

I unfortunately had to install Windows 8.1 in my computer and after doing so, I tried to reinstall GRUB following the next steps:

1. Booted with the Live CD
2. Mounted my system partition:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
   ```
3. Switched to the mounted partition with `arch-chroot`:

   ```
   arch-chroot /mnt
   ```
4. Reinstalled GRUB:

   ```
   grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sda
   grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

Ok, I got GRUB back, Windows is working normally, but when I try to boot Arch, I get a message like:

```
Welcome to emergency mode! After login in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" to try again to boot in default mode.
```

When I log in and type `journalctl -xb`, I get more than 2000 lines, but the only noticeable error is this:

```
systemd[456]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/plymouth: No such file or directory
Subject: Process /bin/plymouth coud not be executed and failed
Defined by: systemd
[...]
```

In fact, there's no such file on `/bin` directory (`/bin/plymouth`).
I'm about to reformat, because I need this computer working.

How and why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the error description had nothing to do with what was going on.

The problem is that the configuration made by `ntfs-3g` to my old windows partition was invalidated when I installed another windows version.

I ran `lsblk` and could notice that the windows partition wasn't mounted. I've tried mount it and ran `systemctl default` to try to boot again in default mode and everything worked just fine.

I went to ntfs-3g, it has detected a new partition on `/dev/sda2` (windows partition), reconfigured it and now my system boots normally.